# iOs application fails to open a file associated with the application (swift)

Tags: swift, file

Good morning everyone I have created an application that will open a file when this gets send as attachment.

When I hold my finger on the file attached to the email my application shows up in the action list as Copy to My application when I touch that application the following code gets executed:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    //url contains a URL to the file your app shall open

    //In my EXAMPLE I would want to read the file as a dictionary\
    do {
        var text2 = try NSString(contentsOfFile: url.absoluteString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return true
}
```

The problem is with the url passed as parameter.  I have check in Xcode and the value of the url is the following:

```
(lldb) po url.absoluteString
"file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/58BE5BE6-10BC-4156-B0D6-6F75193076B3/Documents/Inbox/backup-5.glexport"
```

Which means I do have an URL  but I get the following error:

**The file “backup-5.glexport” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.**

Any Ideas what is wrong with my code??

I am testing this on a device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use url.path!

Comment: Btw you should use String instead of NSString

Comment: Thanks that was the problem thank you very much @LeoDabus

Comment: @LeoDabus make your answer an answer :)